# TypeORM: How to count relationships and turn them into boolean

Tags: typeorm

Is there any way to count the relationship using the loadRelationCountAndMap method and change it to Boolean?

For example, there are comments and user entity, and users can leave likes in the comments.

```js
// comment entity
class Comment extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    public id: number;

    // comment writer
    @ManyToOne(
        type => User,
        user => user.id
    )
    public user: User;

    @ManyToMany(type => User)
    @JoinTable({ name: 'FASHION_COMMENT_LIKE' })
    public likes: User[];
}
```

At this time, I want to print out whether or not a certain user has clicked like, what should I do?

```js
const user: User = await User.findOne({where: id}); 

const comment: Comment = await Comment.createQueryBuilder('comment')
                .leftJoin('comments.likes', 'commentLikes')              
                .loadRelationCountAndMap('comment.isLike', 'comment.likes', 'commentIsLike', qb =>
                    qb.andWhere('commentIsLike.id =  :userId', { userId: user.id }),
                )
```

But it only returns numbers(comment.isLike). Can I change this to Boolean?

Comment: add a little more context and perhaps, the full code.

Comment: I added a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
// comment entity
class Comment extends BaseEntity {
    //.. other columns
    
    @Transform((data) => Boolean(data.value)) // or data.value > 0
    public commentIsLike: boolean;
}
```